# Regex ordinal digit and file size

Tags: regex, string

I have been thinking about a regular expression that can transform a list like this:

```
1. 10.Things.I.Hate.About.You[1999]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray 699.68 MB 
2. 100.Feet.2008.DvDRip-FxM 701.14 MB 
3. 11 - 14 1 286.22 MB 
4. 13_going_on_30(2004)[Brizzly] 700.23 MB 
...
1 523. Waz 699.93 MB 
1 524. We.Own.the.Night[2007]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray 700.87 MB 
1 525. Webs [2003]DVDRip[Xvid AC3[5.1]-RoCK&BlueLadyRG 1 347.70 MB
```

into:

```
10.Things.I.Hate.About.You[1999]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray,699.68 MB
100.Feet.2008.DvDRip-FxM,701.14
11 - 14,1286.22
13_going_on_30(2004)[Brizzly],700.23 
...
Waz,699.93
We.Own.the.Night[2007]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray,700.87
Webs [2003]DVDRip[Xvid AC3[5.1]-RoCK&BlueLadyRG,1347.70
```

Assumption : The filesize is never > 9999.99MB

So far I have a partially working regex:

```
^[^\.]+\. (.+?) (?:([0-9])(?: ))?([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}) MB.*$
```

that maps to

```
$1:$2$3
```

to complete the transformation.

I used the colon because no desktop OS would allow that in a filename, so I am safe.

I built the regex without any formal method (i.e, via using intution) and that very same intution tells me this regex is horrifically complicated and slow!

I wish RegExBuddy had a online version or something similar.

How do I build a better RegEx for the same? Hints, tips...

Comment: Actually, many filesystems allow colons in filenames.  On Linux, a filename can consist of any characters (including control characters) except for NUL (ASCII 0) and slash.  Of course, doing so is really bad practice, and colons should still be avoided in filenames because colon is used as the separator for the $PATH environment variable.

Comment: “DVDRip”? I don’t think we’re supporting infringements of a copyright!

Comment: Ha ha ha ha .. actually this is for a program to test out optimal DVD fitting and then some more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/).

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    next unless /^[^.]+\. (.+?) (?:(\d+) )?(\d+(?:.\d+)?) MB$/ ;
    print "$1,$2$3\n";
}

__DATA__
1. 10.Things.I.Hate.About.You[1999]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray 699.68 MB
2. 100.Feet.2008.DvDRip-FxM 701.14 MB
3. 11 - 14 1 286.22 MB
4. 13_going_on_30(2004)[Brizzly] 700.23 MB
...
1 523. Waz 699.93 MB
1 524. We.Own.the.Night[2007]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray 700.87 MB
1 525. Webs [2003]DVDRip[Xvid AC3[5.1]-RoCK&BlueLadyRG 1 347.70 MB
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> zcx
10.Things.I.Hate.About.You[1999]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray,699.68
100.Feet.2008.DvDRip-FxM,701.14
11 - 14,1286.22
13_going_on_30(2004)[Brizzly],700.23
Waz,699.93
We.Own.the.Night[2007]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray,700.87
Webs [2003]DVDRip[Xvid AC3[5.1]-RoCK&BlueLadyRG,1347.70
```

Answer (score 0):

"I used the colon because no desktop OS would allow that in a filename, so I am safe."

Nice try.  It is allowed under GNU/Linux.

More importantly, you have only given examples.  You have not described what the regex is *intended to do*.  You also have obviously pointless constructs, like (?: ), which could just be a single space.

Finally, it's unclear what role the colon actually plays, as it's not in your replacement text.  Perhaps it would help if you told us what language you're using.

Comment: It's obviously intended to download everything off of the Pirate Bay.

Comment: @Eric +1 for pointing that out. Some of us have never used it.

Comment: Hi! I thought that the question was clear enough? Ahnyways, the regex is suposed t transform lines like "1. 10.Things.I.Hate.About.You[1999]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray 699.68 MB" into "10.Things.I.Hate.About.You[1999]DvDrip[Eng]-Ray,699.68" and I was asking for the best kind of regex to do that - something like what Sinan did..